# Confusion on when and if to use Claims and Roles with Asp.net Identity 2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, claims-based-identity

I'm starting a new ASP.NET project (WebAPI and WebUI) using the Identity 2. What I am struggling to understand is when and if to use claims at all.

My app will require users to login and previously with the old Membership system, I would have added them to a role when they register. Should I continue doing this or is there a better way to handle all of this nowadays?

Wouldnt using Roles and Claims just overcomplicate things?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Always use claims. All .NET identities are claims-based by default. BTW, a role is also a claim - a claim of type ClaimTypes.Role.

Comment: where can we find examples of using claims. I have spent a long time looking and found very little except for some examples using Thinktecture. What I am looking for is a simple ASP.NET WebAPI example.

Comment: agreed, am struggling to find much if not any information this and when you should use this instead of storing in your own custom entities.

Comment: First step in understanding claims-based identity and access control would be reading this book. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff423674.aspx